# Find MAC address of system, using python (in chat system)

Tags: python, macos, chat

Is there any way to find MAC address of a device (in chat system) using Python?

except uuid library

Comment: Is it a local or remote device? If it's a local device on Linux, you can parse the output of `ifconfig`. Or you can parse `/proc/net/arp`, this works even for remote devices.

Comment: its local for now,in future will be developed to work on internet. where widnows do keep arp cache for MAC? thnx for answer

Comment: Are you talking about Windows or Mac now? Please clarify. Please describe your network layout: hosts (what kind of computer, what kind of OS), network types (Ethernet, wifi, internet uplink etc.), topology (switches, hubs, routers).

Comment: MAC i refered to MAC address not MAC computer . the one which i need for my messenger. am asking about windows this time.i know windows can use ipconfig/all then grep the output to get MAC address,but where does windows keep the arp cache?  it would be a chat system,which there is a server,listening to clients,and clients which connect to the server.authentication and MAC address verification happens in server, MAC will get during user registration and will keep in his database

Comment: About where Windows keeps the ARP cache: I don't know, ask on superuser.com or serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's not possible to get a MAC address of another host (computer) on the internet without running your own program on that host, and asking.

It's possible to get the MAC addresses of the active hosts on the local network (up to the next router) from the ARP cache. It's possible to get your own MAC address(es). All this is OS-dependent.